# How do I set up Civ 6 on multiple displays?

Tags: civilization-6, monitor, civilization-6-gathering-storm

I have seen videos and posts talking about playing Civ 6 on three monitors, e.g. [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/civ6/comments/apxaor/multimonitor_support_ui_placement/), [pictures from that post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twuAj.jpg), and [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gqi2bJF_s4M). But I can't seem to figure out how to make that happen on my equipment. I am on Win 10, Civ 6 Gathering Storm up to date.

My goal is probably even trickier. I am playing on a laptop with two outside monitors. I am hoping to play only on those two plugged in screens, but I guess I am still at the first hurtle: how to set up Civ 6 for multi-screen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, it depends on your graphics card if it's possible *at all* and how to activate it. I can only tell how it's done with the DirectX 12 version on a Nvidia GeForce 970 (so with AMD cards the first part will be different). Unfortunately my system is in German, so the actual English phrasing might be a bit different.

1. Open the `NVIDIA SYSTEM SETTINGS` (for this the correct NVIDIA driver need to be installed of course)
2. Under `3d settings` go to `Surround, PhysX configuration`
3. Tick the check box under `Surround-Configuration` that should state something like `Span over multiple displays with Surround` and click on `Config`.
4. Select both monitors by ticking the check boxes. Check for the correct monitor alignment. Note the resolution (e.g. 3840 x 1080), and modify if needed. Click `Activate Surround function`, and close the config window.

Now your Windows desktop should be spanned over both monitors!

Next we need to config Civilization VI itself.

1. Go to `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\Sid Meier's Civilization VI\` (if using Windows 10)
2. Open `AppOptions.txt`
3. Set `RenderWidth` and `RenderHeight` to the configuration noted above (e.g. 3840 and 1080)
4. Set `FullScreen` to `2`
5. Save the file

Now when you start the game it should run spanned over both monitors!

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful!

Comment: Glad to hear. Benefit for me is that in the process I learned for myself how to do it. ;-)

Comment: wow you actually figured it out for Eddie and did not know it beforehand! Amazing Civ players in the world out there :)

Comment: I am playing on a Macbook Pro with the M1 chip (the GPU is the chip too here), gonna try the config options and see if I can get it to work with my portable Asus monitor